# remove in php any character but not symbols and letters

Tags: php, html, replace

how I can use str_ireplace or other functions  to remove any characters but not letters,numbers or symbols that are commonly used in HTML as `: " ' ; :  .  - + =`... etc. I also wants to remove /n, white spaces, tabs and other.

I need that text, comes from doing ("textContent"). innerHTML in IE10 and Chrome, which a php variable are the same size, regardless of which browser do it.Therefore I need the same encoding in both texts and characters that are rare or different are removed.

I try this, but it dont work for me:

```
        $textForMatch=iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);
        $textoForMatc = str_replace(array('\s', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $textoForMatch);
```

$text contains the result of the function ("textContent"). innerHTML, I want to delete characters as �Ã©³..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ], please.

Comment: I think you need to use regular expression. Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: please add a real example input string, and expected output

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option is to simply use preg_replace with a whitelist. I.e. use a pattern listing the things you want to keep, and replace anything not in that list:

```
$input = 'The quick brown 123 fox said "�Ã©³". Man was I surprised';
$stripped = preg_replace('/[^-\w:";:+=\.\']/', '', $input);
$output = 'Thequickbrownfoxsaid"".ManwasIsurprised';
```

### regex explanation

```
/       - start regex
[^      - Begin inverted character class, match NON-matching characters
-       - litteral character
\w      - Match word characters. Equivalent to A-Za-z0-9_
:";:+=  - litteral characters
\.      - escaped period (because a dot has meaning in a regex)
\'      - escaped quote (because the string is in single quotes)
]       - end character class
/       - end of regex
```

This will therefore remove anything that isn't words, numbers or the specific characters listed in the regex.

Comment: thanks but the numbers also do not want to eliminate need something more complex as there are characters �Ã©³

Comment: @Martin The regex will match anything which is **not** explicitly listed (I've taken the liberty of adding a brief explanation to the answer). So to keep numbers, add `0-9` to the list. Everything else will be replaced by `''`, i.e. removed.

Comment: You may want to add the utf-8 modifier to the end of the expression to ensure that non-ascii characters are replaced. Add a `u` after the closing delimiter slash in the regex.

Comment: @Spudley since it's an inverse match - that's not necessary. e.g. input `The quick brown 123 fox said: "こんにちは". Man was I surprised` output `Thequickbrown123foxsaid:"".ManwasIsurprised`